# Failed to connect to the source using the connection manager, merged cells

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, sql-server-2012

Using SSIS and for a certain few sets of data and we get the following error when trying to export it to the database.
[image: MergedCellsError]

The only thing that connects the excel files we are getting this error on is that these are the ones which use merged cells as headings. All our data is in the old .xls format and we have set delay validation to true, the data also definitely exists in the location we have specified.

Comment: Are you selecting a range with a select statement? If so are you selecting the left most field in Excel? An example of the data you are trying to load would be helpful!

Comment: @MiguelH - it's a spreadsheet of sales data, which we are moving all of into our database. the client has merged the first cell into a title and we believe it is this that is causing the error. We would manually change it but for the fact that it is an automated process that will need doing quite often.

Comment: Have you tried a select statement which ignores the title? This example 'SELECT * FROM [sheetx$A2:J100]' selects from "sheetx" column A row 2 to J100. This skips over a title line